# Cloud SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have Cloud SQL instance(16 vCPUs, Memory 128 GB, SSD storage 300 GB). Db size 110GB.

When I execute a complex query from the cloud windows VM using SQL Server Management Studio(this vm is in the same VPC as SQL Server), it always takes on average 35s.
When I execute the same query locally (connected to the same SQL server instance with sql proxy) from a mac machine(8 cores, 16 gb RAM) using DBeaver it takes 1.5s on average.

I can't figure out why such a difference. I even tried connecting from vm to SQL server with sql proxy, but still no change.

Please help to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Server Management Studio is asking for some tables / permissions on the server and times out.

Cloud SQL is a *managed* database and you simply cannot do all administration tasks a normal MSSQL database would allow you yo do.

When you use DBeaver does not try to manage the server: it just sends the query and retrieves the results. If you run DBeaver from your Windows VM, or a VM in the same VPC you'll get that 1.5s/query.

Comment: Thank you so so much! That solved the problem.